# Why is my deamon not printing to console after I re-launch it?

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, daemon

Here is my code:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();

    if (pid != 0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    setsid();
    chdir("/");

    while(1){
        sleep(4);
        printf("%s\n", "Hello world!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Ok now I will open the Terminal, and start bash inside again, and the output will be:

```
Last login: Tue Jun  2 14:29:49 on ttys000
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ bash
bash-3.2$ ./a.out 
bash-3.2$ Hello world!
Hello world!
Hello world!
exit
exit
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$ Hello world!
Hello world!
```

What I want to show here is that, I started terminal, which starts bash as far as I know, and inside the bash I started one more bash and started my program.

Even that I exited the bash, the deamon was still running, which is what I was expecting..

But the problem is, if I quit the Terminal application, and start it again, I will not see "Hello World" anymore..

All I see is:

```
Last login: Tue Jun  2 14:30:46 on ttys000
Korays-MacBook-Pro:~ koraytugay$
```

Is my deamon dead after I close the terminal? Why in the first situation, even that I exit bash, the parent bash still shows the Hello Worlds, but not after I re-start the Terminal?

This is what I mean by Terminal: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-mac-os-x-command-line

Also I want to add this information,

In the new terminal when I execute

```
ps -A
```

I am still seeing:

```
41891 ??         0:00.01 ./a.out
41902 ??         0:00.01 ./a.out
```

However no text? Why is no text sent to standard out? The deamons still execute as far as I can tell, and the terminal is showing me the standard out, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected, due to the fact that when you quit the terminal file handler to which you application writes its output (**stdout**) is gone. When you start the terminal again it does not restore the same file handler. This is the same if your app is writing in a file and you have deleted it. If you create new  file with same path it will not continue to write inside. If you want to keep the output, after the terminal is you have to write in a file, like log file from daemons like httpd, samba, sshd, etc.

Comment: Isn't standard out always 0? What do you mean the file is a different file?

Comment: check with `lsof` open file descriptors of your app. You will then see where is stdout pointing.

Answer (score 3):

You have forked from the initial `bash` instance which connects the stdin, stdout and stderr with a specific terminal. When you terminate the bash instance the terminal to which the stdin, stdout and stderr were connected will be closed, and therefore for your daemon writing to any of these descriptors is effectively writing to a descriptor linked to a removed file or device.

Answer (score 1):

If a terminal is closed, all processes who write to that TTY device will have their standard output closed. Opening a new terminal will not cause the close `stdout` to be magically restored.

Comment: Isn't stdout something global? How can it be closed? Does every process has its own stdout?

Comment: And why closing the terminal closes the stdout file? Why exiting the bash (as in my first example) does not close the stdout?

Comment: @KorayTugay There's a difference between a *shell* and a *terminal*. The shell is a program that reads input and parses it and executes commands, a terminal is a device to handle input and output. A process is connected to a terminal device, if that device is closed of course the processes using that device can't continue writing to that device.

Comment: What do you mean a terminal is a device? Isn't it just another program?

Comment: @KorayTugay The terminal *program* sets up a terminal *device* (also known as a TTY device) for the input and output. I think you need to search for and read a little more about terminal devices, and how POSIX terminal I/O works.

Comment: Can you suggesst any good readings? Because I am totally confused right now.